# Incompatible types. Require: Object, Found: String?

Tags: java, string, list, object, generics

I am trying to use Google Sheets API for Reading and Writing on my App.

(Now I am reading [Google Sheets API Tutorial documents](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values))

I got an error which said

#### ERROR

```
Incompatible types.
Required: List<java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>
Found: List<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>
```

#### Code

```
List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(
        // Cell values ...
        "apple", "banana"
    )
    // Additional rows ...
);
```

I think that String has Object properties because of `public final class String extends Object` in Java. (See [this oracle documents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)) But, I am wondering why I got error. And I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: [Works for me.](https://ideone.com/opwDGb) How are you compiling this?

Comment: @shmosel In Android Studio 3.0.1, with JDK 1.8.0_151, compileSdkVersion 26. No other special option because this is example app for practice.

Comment: Then I suspect you're not sharing the actual code. Did you try compiling the actual snippet posted here?

Comment: @shmosel Yes. This is exactly what I code in my Android Studio. See this Imgur Image [Link](https://i.imgur.com/mimD2aC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code seems to work fine in Java 9, in earlier versions you can coerce the first argument to [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) to the expected type and it should work as expected. Like,

```
List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList((Object) "apple", "banana"));
```

Note the `Object` cast on `"apple"` causes the java compiler to treat all subsequent items as `Object`.

Comment: Or `Arrays.<Object>asList(...)`

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between casting type which means ```(Object) "apple"``` and not? I know what casting is, but I cannot understand why compiler had confusion. I think both are okay because String class extends Object directly as I mentioned with Java Doc [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)